# How do I hide a Formly field in using conditions based on the value of a field in a different form-group using expressions?

Tags: ngx-formly

In formly docs, you can create hide expressions like this:

```
{
  key: 'iLikeTwix',
  type: 'checkbox',
  props: {
    label: 'I like twix',
  },
  expressions: { hide: '!model.name' },
}
```

Or like this:

```
{
  key: 'country',
  type: 'input',
  props: {
    label: 'Country',
    placeholder: 'set city field to 123'
  },
  expressions: {
    hide: (field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
      return field.model?.city === "123";
    },
  }
},
```

However, how do I reference another field's value when it is in another field group. I want this WITHOUT USING THE FUNCTION METHOD, as this is supposed to be saved as a valid json.

e.g.

```
  [
    {
      key: 'parentField1',
      fieldGroup: [
        {
          key: 'state',
          type: 'input',
          props: {
            label: 'State',
            placeholder: 'Enter State'
          }
        },
        {
          key: 'country',
          type: 'input',
          props: {
            label: 'Country',
            placeholder: 'set city field to 123'
          },
          expressions: {
            hide: "model?.age === '123'",
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 'age',
      type: 'input',
      props: {
        label: 'Age',
        placeholder: 'set city field to 123'
      }
    }
  ]
```

I can not get to access the referenced field model.